# display woocommerce all category title on home page

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, homepage

how can i display in my theme all woocommerce category title are custom filed value.

example html like bellow

```
<li><a href="#">
          <div>
            <h2>category title</h5>
            <h3>custom field one value</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="imgpos">custom field two value</div>
          </a></li>
```

i tried many way but still not success

```
<?php
$post_type = 'product';
// Get all the taxonomies for this post type
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( (object) array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );
foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) : 
    // Gets every "category" (term) in this taxonomy to get the respective posts
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
    foreach( $terms as $term ) : 
        $posts = new WP_Query( "taxonomy=$taxonomy&term=$term->slug&posts_per_page=2" );
        if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();
          ?>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></a><br><br>
          <?php
        endwhile; endif;
    endforeach;
endforeach;
?>
```

**UPDATE 1**
bellow code only give me category title and link but can not figure out how to get costume filed value also

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'number'     => $number,
    'orderby'    => 'title',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
    'include'    => $ids
);
$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
$count = count($product_categories);
if ( $count > 0 ){
    foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {
        echo '<h4><a href="' . get_term_link( $product_category ) . '">' . $product_category->name . '</a></h4>';
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    // 'terms' => 'white-wines'
                    'terms' => $product_category->slug
                )
            ),

        );

    }
}

?>
```

example for get custom value code will be bellow. i want fit that inside div

```
 <?php if( get_field('hexagon_thumbnail') ): ?>

    <img src="<?php the_field('hexagon_thumbnail'); ?>" />

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to display a list of categories or a list of products with the categories and meta data in which are attached to the products?

Comment: thanks for comment. i want to display list of  categories . Title and two custom filed value. i used AFC so code will be like <?php the_field('custom_text'); ?> and <?php 

$image = get_field('image');

if( !empty($image) ): ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

<?php endif; ?>

Comment: @pagol007 Please file an [edit] and add the info in your comment above directly inside your question. Code in comments are unreadable, also, valueble info that can help others in answering your question should be **inside** your question, not a useless comments ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$post_type = 'product';

$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies((object) array( 'post_type' => $post_type ));

foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) : 

    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);

    foreach ($terms as $term) : 

        $term_link = get_term_link($term->term_id);

        $posts = new WP_Query( "taxonomy=$taxonomy&term=$term->slug&posts_per_page=2" ); ?>

        <li>

            <h2>
                <a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
            </h2>

            <?php 

            if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>

                <div>

                <?php if( get_field('hexagon_thumbnail') ): ?>

                    <img src="<?php the_field('hexagon_thumbnail'); ?>" />

                <?php endif; ?>

                </div>

            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

        </li> <!-- end list item -->

<?php endforeach; endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: thanks for your great help. actually now showing category with two other post. and post link i want only woocommcer category and category link and costume filed value. costume value not coming now. only coming category title. permalink coming from product post.

i only want category name. with category links and custom filed value i think my query having problem.

Comment: i got one code. which is bit work. you can check. i just updated my post

Comment: I made an edit to the example above... try that.

Comment: nah it is result same. only title come also 2 post come. too. i think this query $posts = new WP_Query( "taxonomy=$taxonomy&term=$term->slug&posts_per_page=2" ); .. page post per page. i dont want post per page. i want only category title.  i updated new code that is fine disply only category with permalink but no idea inside there how i can get custom filed value

Comment: Your code is quite expensive to run and hits the db quite hard ;-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen who me? If so... I know, right now I am not addressing that, it is an adhoc copy and paste from the OPs original code. Just trying to get on the same page as him in terms of what he wants because in one instance he says one thing and in another - something else. :)

Comment: @pagol007 If you don't want the posts to come along with the category, then get rid of the call to `WP_Query`. The issue however is you want to bring a custom field along with the Category title and link, ok... Where is that metadata (custom field) stored? In postmeta, usermeta or assigned against category? What table...?

Comment: i remove wp_query .. but not work. for custom filed i use advancedcustomfields plugins. i have no idea thats table. but i know how to get value from advancedcustomfields i did it but not work. i think if i just get value from my updated code then will be fine. my updated work fine for category title and permalink

Comment: if you use just `get_value('key')` then you must be inside `the_loop` otherwise you have to do `get_value('key', $posd_id)`, but you need to know the post_id and the way to do that is to query the posts in taxonomy term.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the value of ACF in the product loop you need to pass the id of the product, if the acf in product, or if the ACF in product category the id will be term id followed by product_cat_{term_id} as the second parameter of the the_field or get field function.

Comment: Where is this ACF coming from, OP didn't mention about it.

Comment: @bravokeyl The OP is using `get_field()`, very likely from ACF.

Comment: @toscho  got it.